# Are BuildCraft and IndustrialCraft compatible with each other?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-industrialcraft

I installed IndustrialCraft into my BuildCraft game, as I would like to have electric (or some other renewable energy powered) engines using the IndustrialCraft power running my buildcraft custom sized quarries to extract resources for equivalent exchange to convert into building materials.

Do these mods work with each other? If so, what is an example setup?

Comment: Yogscast. On mobile so can't be bothered with the faff to find for now...

Comment: I'll double check yogscast (the technic pack videos inspired me to try these mods) but I don't recall them joining the quarry from buildcraft with the electricity (or other means of fuel) from industrialcraft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Currently no. However if I get off my lazy butt I am halfway through writing a mod to make a new BC engine that runs off of IC power. Keep a eye out for leftler on the Minecraft forms. (I will post a link here too when it is done.)</s>

It appears I was too lazy and someone beat me to it. [Here is a link](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=2444) to a mod that will do it.

Comment: Just a note, when I figured out how to use conductive pipes, it got considerably easier to work with engines and such as I was able to properly space them out and avoid overheating and all.

Answer (score 1):

Mod that allows you to get MJs from EUs is [Forestry](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki/), you can use Electrical Engine to do that.

Electrical Engines require 6 EU/t to produce 2 MJ/t. They accept packets of any size (so can be connected to HV or extreme voltage cables directly). Will not ovearheat. Can be upgraded to change either power requirements or amount of produced energy with electron tubes, details [on project's website](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki/index.php?n=Machines.EngineTin).

Sadly it does not add a generator able to run on MJs to produce EUs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a block called the Energy Link which converts EU to MJ. There is also one that does the opposite.